# ¿Cómo usar múltiples reglas en htaccess(rewriterule)?

Tags: html, web, .htaccess

Estoy usando `htaccess` pero no logro enlazar más de 1 regla, y eso me restringe a solo poder usar `POST` para el paso de variables por enlaces, algún consejo de como usar más de 1 regla y no generar conflictos.

Dejo un ejemplo de lo que he intentado:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1&valor1=$2 [N]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L] (este es el que uso por el momento)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que tratar las reglas por separado. Todas las reglas precedentes se aplican a una sola regla. Las reglas siguientes no son tocadas por esa regla.

Mire este ejemplo:

```
www.foo.com/Home/
www.foo.com/en/Home
www.foo.com/Article/1
www.foo.com/en/Article/1
```

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1&article=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Devjoel gracias por la atención!